# Code first generating strange column

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC 4 application that is using code first to generate tables and columns in my SQL Server DB. I am trying to figure out how I ended up with an additional TABLE that was not intended. I have looked through some questions but not found the exact same problem I am having. I will try to explain this simply.

I have added a model called Associate which keeps track of associates that my client does business with. Each Associate needs a foriegn key of AssociateTypedID and RegionID.

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class Associate
        {
            public int AssociateId { get; set; }
            public string AssociateName { get; set; }
            public int AddressNumber { get; set; }
            public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Zipcode { get; set; }
            public string MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string AssociateEmail { get; set; }
            public string AssociateWebsite { get; set; }
            public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }
            public string ContactLastName { get; set; }
            public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
            public int RegionId { get; set; }
            public int AssociateTypeId { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<AssociateType> AssociateTypes { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

AND

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class AssociateType
        {
            public int AssociateTypeId { get; set; }
            public string AssociateTypeName { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Associate> Associates { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

AND

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class Region
        {
            public int RegionId { get; set; }
            public int RegionName { get; set; }
            public int RegionDescription { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Associate> Associates { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

AND

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class XXXDb : DbContext
        {
            public XXXDb(): base("name=DefaultConnection")
            { 

            }
            public DbSet<Associate> Associates { get; set; }
            public DbSet<AssociateType> AssociateTypes { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So I have updated my code above and I'm getting very close to where I need to be in my database. I have the following tables generated.

Associates, AssociateTypes & Regions (each of them have the columns I would expect)

BUT I now have a new table called RegionAssociates which has the following columns:

Region_RegionId (int) & Associate_AssociateId (int)

This table was not expected or needed in my schema.

Comment: I just deleted the RegionAssociates Table inside the database then ran Update-Database -Force and it did not return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes doesn't match your description of the model. You are saying

> Each Associate can have a designation of AssociateType

I suppose that the same `AssociateType` can be assigned to more `Associate`s, so there should be 1:N relationship between `AssociateType` and `Associate`.

But the `Associate` class defines the relationship the other way around - by convention `public virtual ICollection<AssociateType> AssociateType { get; set; }` creates 1:N relationship between `Associate` and `AssociateType`.

the correct definition of your classes would be

```
public class Associate
    {
        public int AssociateId { get; set; }
        public string AssociateName { get; set; }
        public int AddressNumber { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string AssociateEmail { get; set; }
        public string AssociateWebsite { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public int AssociateTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual AssociateType AssociateType { get; set; }
        public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ContactLastName { get; set; }
        public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }

public class AssociateType
    {
        public int AssociateTypeId { get; set; }
        public string AssociateTypeName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Associate> Associates { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: OK, I get it now, Looking back on my other model not shown here where I did it the right way I see what I did wrong. Just read up a little bit more on ICollection. Long night working last night and I just didn't fully understand what I was doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, so I ran a Update-Database migration command and it dropped my AssociateType table. That shouldn't have happened?

Comment: No this shouldn't have happend. Have you added this property `public virtual AssociateType AssociateType { get; set; }` to the `Associate` class? It necessary to have a navigation property beside the foreign key `AssociateTypeId` to make it work without configuration. Another option is to use fluent configuration.

Comment: Lets assume that Each Associate could have an AssociateType column represented by the corresponding AssociateTypeID. And Each Associate can also have a Region column represented by a RegionID, I am updating my original code to show my Region class as well. do you think you could update your example above to show the right way each class should be setup?

Comment: The `RegionAssociates` table appears in your database because you are creating N:M relationship between `Associate` and `Region`. If you want an `Associate` to have only one region, you should remove `Regions` property and add a new `public virtual Region Region {get; set; }` property

Comment: Thanks Luke. I seem to have a grasp on it now. I appreciate this last comment. Helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure what is missing from your configuration as you did't post it, but if you are using the fluent api something like this should fix the problem:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssociateType>()
.HasKey(t => t.AssociateTypeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Associate>()
.HasRequired(t => t.AssociateType)
.WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Associate);
```

The above is adapted from this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: Hi Olav, 

So in the case I were to use the API to set relationships (Which I'm not doing now) I would put the code you have below in my Configuration.cs file inside my migrations folder right?

Comment: Fluent API configurations goes into the OnModelCreating of your DbContext class, or preferrably in separate EntityTypeConfiguration<AssociateType> and EntityTypeConfiguration<Associate> classes that you add to your modelBuilder like this: modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssociateTypeConfiguration()).

Comment: I see Olav, you cleared that up for me. I am not using the Fluent API right now. But I understand how to implement it if needed. It goes in my DbContext class. I thank you for your help, but right now I am working with JUST the POCO Classes to try and get the results I want.